# Library versions string in autoconf

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake

What is correct way of specifying a library version for first time in autoconf? The library is in unstable status and I suppose it's gonna be `0.1.0` until it's prepared for the public API which should be `1.0.0`. So I put following in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SUBST([FOO_SO_VERSION], [0:1:0])
AC_SUBST([FOO_API_VERSION], [0.1.0])
```

And also in `Makefile.am`:

```
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info $(FOO_SO_VERSION)
```

Though I get this file:

```
libfoo.so.0.0.1
```

Comment: What library are you talking about? Does it have a pkgconfig version?

Comment: @BrettHale The library I'm working on :P And, yes it does.

Comment: The answer by @ptomato is the right way to handle versioning - but *if* you're sure the library is only for internal use, you *can* use the `-release` flag. You always seem to be working on something interesting:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .so version should always start at 0:0:0. It should not be tied to your project's software version number.

Libtool version numbers are referred to as *current:revision:age* and don't necessarily map to the .so file's suffix on any particular platform.

Here is a summary of the explanation given at [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html):

- Increase the *revision* every time you make a release.
- Increase the *current* value and set *revision* to 0 every time you make a change to the API/ABI.
- Increase the *age* when you make a backwards-compatible change to the API/ABI.
- Set *age* to 0 when you make a backwards-incompatible change to the API/ABI.